`git mv` a submodule folder does not rename it
I have tried renaming the folder for a submodule in my repo with git mv, but it is not doing what I actually wanted (and I am avoiding doing something more complicated and messing up the repo, because I'm not well-versed with git).
What happens
Upon calling git mv old-path new-path, where old-path/ is the folder containing a submodule (a .git whose content is gitdir: ../.git/modules/<submodule-name>), I get back a submodule located at new-path/oldpath/, instead of simply new-path/.
The content of .gitmodules also change such that the path variable is path = new-path/old-path.
How to achieve the desired behavior of git mv of putting the submodule into new-path/?

Did a folder named new-path already exist?

Yes it did. The folder not existing solves the renaming problem apparently, thank you. My mistake involved the fact that I wanted to move to a subfolder and rename: old-path to new/path. It returned fatal: renaming 'old-path' failed: No such file or directory, which prompted me to create new/path, to which git mv returned new/path/old-path.
